# How to filter duplicate records having multiple key in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I want to delete some records in Data Frame-A based on some common column values in Data Frame-B.

For Example:
    Data Frame-A:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 7
4 7 9 6
2 5 7 9
```

Data Frame-B:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 7
2 5 7 4
2 9 8 7
```

```
Keys: A,B,C columns
```

Desired Output:

```
A B C D
3 4 5 7
4 7 9 6
```

Any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `left anti-join`:

```
df_a.join(df_b, Seq("A","B","C"), "leftanti").show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  4|  5|  7|
|  4|  7|  9|  6|
+---+---+---+---+
```