# Spark: how to filter rows without using any joins?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have two dataframes, **df1** and **df2**. Both **df1** and **df2** contains the "id" column. I want to filter **df1**, such that the resultant df, **df1prime**, has

- only the ids found in **df1**
- none of the all ids found in **df2**,

Without using any joins. How can I do this? Will going back to RDDs instead of DFs help? Both pyspark and scala responses are welcomed.

Thanks!

Edit: I would like to keep the entire rows from df1

Comment: what's wrong with joins? see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351669/how-to-filter-duplicate-records-having-multiple-key-in-spark-dataframe/)

Comment: Nothing specifically wrong with joins, but I would like to look for a more inexpensive operation

Comment: an anti join will be the most inexpensive operation if you have dataframes, if you want to work with `rdd`'s you can use `cougroup()` and then filter.

Comment: Sorry how is this a possible duplicate?

Comment: Based on your description, you are trying to achieve the exact same thing. If that's not the case, please share example data and expected output, along with the code you have tried. If it is the case, as mentioned earlier, you won't find a more efficient solution than anti-join, unless df2 is small enough to use it as a broadcast variable.

Comment: Yes I am indeed trying to achieve the same thing, as this is a very common operation when working with data. My objective of asking this question to look outside of my current knowledge to see if it is possible to accomplish such manipulations, barring the use of joins. So there I appreciate your statement that there will not be a more efficient solution than an anti-join

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want the ids in your `df1prime` (as you state in your question), then you can simply do (scala):

```
val df1primeIDs = df1.select($"id").except(df2.select($"id"))
```

If you need the entire columns of `df1`, without a join, I don't see any other option than (with my line above and assuming that `id` is of type long):

```
val df1prime = df1.where($"id".isin(
   df1primeIDs.collect().map(_.getLong(0)):_*)
 )
```

But normally collection is not an option...

Comment: Ah i would like to still have all the columns in df1. Collecting would be very expensive..